# Best syntax for @if with multiple OR and if inner

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, syntax

I need your help about a syntax in C# :

here is my actual code:

```
<div class="class">
    <h5>MySuperTitle</h5>
    <ul>
        @if (Ms.Cs.value1 != null)
        {
            <li> My Li1 <span>@Ms.Cs.value1</span> </li>
        }
        @if (Ms.Cs.value2 != 0)
        {
            <li> My Li2 <span>@Ms.Cs.value2</span> </li>
        }
        @if (true)
        {
            <li> My Li3 <span>--</span></li>
        }
        @if (Ms.Cs.value4 != 0)
        {
            <li> My Li4 <span>@Ms.Cs.value4</span></li>
        }
        @if (Ms.Cs.value5 != null)
        {
            <li> My Li5 <span>@Ms.Cs.value5</span></li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I'm looking for is to add a @if conditional on "MySuperTitle" too to hide it if there is no "sub" value.

Have i to add a `@if (Ms.Cs.value1 != null) || (Ms.Cs.value2 != 0) || (Ms.Cs.value4 != 0) .....` ?

Or is there an better syntax ? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: If you have control over whatever class your `Cs` property is, then just make a method there that returns a bool, have that check all the properties so you are keeping your code DRY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could determine that separately in a render function code-block.

Note you can make your Razor code more succinct by using same-line opening-braces:

```
<div class="class">
@{
    Boolean hasAnyData = Ms.Cs.value1 != null || Ms.Cs.value2 != 0 || Ms.Cs.value4 != 0 || Ms.Cs.value5 != null;
}
    @if( hasAnyData ) {
    <h5>MySuperTitle</h5>
    <ul>
        @if (Ms.Cs.value1 != null) {
            <li> My Li1 <span>@Ms.Cs.value1</span> </li>
        }
        @if (Ms.Cs.value2 != 0) {
            <li> My Li2 <span>@Ms.Cs.value2</span> </li>
        }
        @if (true) {
            <li> My Li3 <span>--</span></li>
        }
        @if (Ms.Cs.value4 != 0) {
            <li> My Li4 <span>@Ms.Cs.value4</span></li>
        }
        @if (Ms.Cs.value5 != null) {
            <li> My Li5 <span>@Ms.Cs.value5</span></li>
        }
    </ul>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, one more question please: 
If I create many Boolean (for each #class I have), can I use them like `@if (hasAnyData1 !=0 || hasAnyData2 !=0 || hasAnyData3 !=0) { ... }` ? 
thanks

Comment: @Johan That won't work because `hasAnyData2` would be `Boolean` but `0` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using ViewModel. If so, in your ViewModel, you might want to do it like:

```
public bool Value1Exists
{
    get
    {
        return Value1 != null
    }
}
...
public bool HasItems
{
    get
    {
        if (Value1Exists || Value2Exists || ...)
             return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Then in your razor view:

```
@if(Ms.HasItems) {
    <h5>MySuperTitle</h5>
    <ul>
        @if (Ms.Value1Exists) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    </ul>
}
```